# Displaying directories stored within a directory

Tags: php, directory, file-handling

I've just watched these videos on displaying images from a directory and would like some help modifiying the code.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHq1MNnhSzU - part 1

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL-tOG8zGcQ -part 2

What the videos show is almost exactly what I wanted, but the system I have in mind is for photo galleries.

I plan on having a folder called galleries, which will contain other folders, one each for each different photo sets ie

- Galleries

  - Album 1
  - Album 2

I would like some help to modify the code so that it can identify and display only the directories on one page. That way I can convert those directories into links that take you to the albums themselves, and use the orignal code to pull the images in from there.

For those that want the video code, here it is

```
$dir = 'galleries';
$file_display = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
echo 'Directory \'', $dir , '\' not found!';
} else {
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);

foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
        echo '<img src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" />';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: YOu need to know two things: the is_dir() function, and the concept of recursion.

Comment: You want to kick ass?  Leverage this in your solution: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php  How to use it?  Well RTFM and if still not clear a great approach is to search on github and see how others have used it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function like this to list all of the directories:

```
function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){ 

$ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' ); 
// Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts 
// will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin. 

$dh = @opendir( $path ); 
// Open the directory to the handle $dh 

while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){ 
// Loop through the directory 

    if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){ 
    // Check that this file is not to be ignored 

        $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) ); 
        // Just to add spacing to the list, to better 
        // show the directory tree. 

        if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 
        // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down... 

            echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
            getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 
            // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
            // this is what makes function recursive. 

        } else { 

            echo "$spaces $file<br />"; 
            // Just print out the filename 

        } 

    } 

} 

closedir( $dh ); 
// Close the directory handle 

}
```

Then, pass the directory a user selected in as your $dir variable to the function you currently have.

Comment: Hi I've tried using your example above but I can't get any output. I assume function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){ is just setting the path to the base directory itself.

I did try creating a $path variable just incase and still didn't get any output, is there something I've overlooked?

Comment: call the function using the $dir directory in your example getDirectory($dir);

Answer (score 0):

I can't test any code right now but would love to see a solution here along the lines of:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/galleries');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

SPL is powerful and should be used more.

The **RecursiveDirectoryIterator** provides an interface for iterating recursively over filesystem directories. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php